# Date Class error in java

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I have `Date today=new Date();` which returns the current date.. but when i try to display date,month,year separately with the help of

```
DateFormat mmFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM"); 
System.out.println(mmFormat.format(today.getMonth()));
DateFormat yyFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy"); 
System.out.println(yyFormat.format(today.getYear()));
```

it prints month as 01 and year as 1970

how to resolve this.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mmFormat.format(today.getMonth())
```

You're passing an *integer* – the month of the date – to a date format method.

The format method interprets that integer as a UNIX timestamp – a number of seconds since 1970.

You need to pass the date itself to the formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the entire date to SimpleDateFormat. The format string "MM" or "yyyy" will cause it to just extract the part of the date you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Date` `today` as the input argument

```
System.out.println(mmFormat.format(today));
```

and

```
System.out.println(yyFormat.format(today));
```

Answer (score 0):

`today.getMonth()` and `today.getYear()` returns an `int` which is interpreted as an UNIX timestamp . The value is `1` and `113` , which corresponds to approximately `January 1, 1970, 00:00:01 GMT` and `January 1, 1970, 00:01:53 GMT` represented by this `Date` object. To get the desired result , you need to pass the `Date` object :

```
System.out.println(mmFormat.format(today));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Calendar. Have a look at the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

You can do it like this -

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)); // month in the Calendar class begins from 0
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

This would help you to avoid creating multiple `DateFormat` objects. Also in case you want to use another date instead of today's date the you can just pass the `date` to the `cal.setTime()` method.

Answer (score 0):

That is because all these methods are deprecated. Use

```
 Calendar myCalendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
 myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better in this way

```
    Date date=new Date(); // your date
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(year+"\n"+month);
```